# Submiting data through form in db

Tags: php, database, forms

I have a problem with my php script through which i need to send data to db. When i send data, i get blank screen, no matter what I write, select and everything else.

```
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
 mysql_select_db("gagq", $con);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gagq.user WHERE id=1;");
 echo $result;
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

basically , i get blank screen from this. i access the file through the form, submit button. Method post, action name of file. Now, i've filled the db on id=1, but no matter what i write, on php nothing works. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gagq.user WHERE id=1;");

$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="hr" xml:lang="hr">
<head>
 <title>AMD Advanced Micro Devices</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 echo "damn";
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
 mysql_select_db("gagq", $con);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gagq.user WHERE id=1;");
 echo $result;
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
 <body>
 </html>

Comment: this is the whole code of the php file. NOTHING works. i don't know why. no error, no nothing. i open this file through
<form id="logf" method="post" action="akcija.php">

Comment: with submit button 
<input type="submit" id="gumbl" value="Go!"/>

all the files are placed in htdocs in xampp folder. please help, as i can't see any errors in what i'm doing...

Comment: is it giving any error? and please look the solution above to fetch the data. $result doesn't have any data, and use print_r to print the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in a testing phase, you should include:

```
/* Turns Error Reporting ON */
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in order to see and correct any php errors, rather than adding die checking everywhere.